# Circular progressbar to show RecyclerView progress

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-progressbar

I created a home screen to my app and it consists of 3 Horizontal RecyclerVIews as follows:

[image]

All of the three are created in the same way by using this:

```
public class DiscoverItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DiscoverItemAdapter.DiscoverItemsViewHolder> {

    private List<DiscoverItems> discoverItems;

    interface OnDiscoverItemClickListener {
        void onClick(DiscoverItems discoverItems);
    }

    private OnDiscoverItemClickListener listener;

    public DiscoverItemAdapter(List<DiscoverItems> discoverItems, OnDiscoverItemClickListener listener) {
        this.discoverItems = discoverItems;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public DiscoverItemsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_Item_discover, parent, false);
        return new DiscoverItemsViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(DiscoverItemsViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bind(discoverItems.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return discoverItems.size();
    }

    class DiscoverItemsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView ItemName;
        ImageView ItemCover;
        DiscoverItems discoverItems;

        private DiscoverItemsViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ItemName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_ItemName);
            ItemCover = itemView.findViewById( R.id.iv_ItemCover );
            itemView.setOnClickListener( v -> listener.onClick(discoverItems) );

        }

        private void bind(DiscoverItems discoverItems) {
            this.discoverItems = discoverItems;
            String ItemID = discoverItems.getItemID();

            MyItemClient client = new MyItemClient();
            client.getItems(ItemID, new JsonHttpResponseHandler(){
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response){
                    if(response!=null){
                        final MyItem Items = MyItem.fromJson(response);

                        ItemName.setText( Items.getTitle() );
                        Picasso.with(itemView.getContext()).load( Uri.parse(Items.getCoverUrl())).into(ItemCover);
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    }


}
```

I would like to show a circular `ProgressBar` in the middle of the screen until all of the `RecyclerViews` are full of the items.

I tried to use

```
pb_Discover.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
----CALLING THE RECYCLERVIEW-----
pb_Discover.setVisibility( View.GONE);
```

However, it sets the visibility to `GONE` right when it finished the call even though the RecyclerView is not yet populated.

Where can I place the line `pb_Discover.setVisibility( View.GONE);` so it will really disappear only after all of the `RecyclerViews` are populated?

**Solution**:

I managed to solve this by adding:

```
rv_PopularItems.getViewTreeObserver()
        .addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                flagscounter = flagscounter + 1;
                CheckViewsLoaded(flagscounter);
                rv_PopularItems.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            }
        });
```

I do so in each one of the RecyclerViews and then if `flagcounter = 3`, I setVisibility to `GONE`

Thank you

Comment: How do you populate recyclerview ?